# Indirect transformation based on a list of data points

Tags: list-manipulation, integral-transforms

I have a set of data which describes the Intensity function $Int(q)$ as a function of $q$. The data list provided below provides the shape of $Int(q)$ versus $q$.How can I use this information to obtain a profile of  the distribution function $P(r)$ which is given by

Int[q_] := 4*Pi*Integrate[P[r]*(Sin[q*r]/(q*r)), {r, 0, Infinity}]

```
data = 
  {{0.020024338`, 5.2050893`}, {0.022380134`, 
4.5086694`}, {0.024735928`, 3.9553359`}, {0.027091718`, 
3.5031466`}, {0.029447506`, 3.136435`}, {0.031803289`, 
2.8969679`}, {0.034159069`, 2.720232`}, {0.036514845`, 
2.5742439`}, {0.038870616`, 2.4916894`}, {0.041226383`, 
2.4135635`}, {0.043582144`, 2.3849718`}, {0.0459379`, 
2.3480797`}, {0.048293651`, 2.3245857`}, {0.050649396`, 
2.2766608`}, {0.053005134`, 2.2146618`}, {0.055360866`, 
2.11396`}, {0.057716592`, 1.9738159`}, {0.06007231`, 
1.8161727`}, {0.062428021`, 1.6357164`}, {0.064783725`, 
1.4384744`}, {0.06713942`, 1.2478508`}, {0.069495108`, 
1.0708938`}, {0.071850787`, 0.92539427`}, {0.074206457`, 
0.80211808`}, {0.076562119`, 0.70167624`}, {0.078917771`, 
0.61047034`}, {0.081273413`, 0.53489188`}, {0.083629045`, 
0.47277132`}, {0.085984668`, 0.42150623`}, {0.08834028`, 
0.37787423`}, {0.090695881`, 0.34278684`}, {0.093051471`, 
0.31405959`}, {0.09540705`, 0.28720344`}, {0.097762617`, 
0.26768603`}, {0.10011817`, 0.24819699`}, {0.10247372`, 
0.23306143`}, {0.10482925`, 0.21905138`}, {0.10718476`, 
0.20982442`}, {0.10954027`, 0.19673289`}, {0.11189576`, 
0.18747296`}, {0.11425124`, 0.18110339`}, {0.1166067`, 
0.17339579`}, {0.11896215`, 0.16572`}, {0.12131759`, 
0.16089015`}, {0.12367301`, 0.15379156`}, {0.12602842`, 
0.15027508`}, {0.12838381`, 0.14365307`}, {0.13073918`, 
0.14074507`}, {0.13309454`, 0.13529032`}, {0.13544988`, 
0.13080442`}, {0.13780521`, 0.12837494`}, {0.14016052`, 
0.12438591`}, {0.14251581`, 0.11990755`}, {0.14487109`, 
0.11814154`}, {0.14722634`, 0.11381641`}, {0.14958158`, 
0.11098607`}, {0.1519368`, 0.10826816`}, {0.15429201`, 
0.10610327`}, {0.15664719`, 0.10442405`}, {0.15900236`, 
0.10108521`}, {0.1613575`, 0.097974014`}, {0.16371263`, 
0.096837303`}, {0.16606774`, 0.092660264`}, {0.16842282`, 
0.090975641`}, {0.17077789`, 0.089248284`}, {0.17313293`, 
0.087246505`}, {0.17548796`, 0.085425973`}, {0.17784296`, 
0.08372304`}, {0.18019794`, 0.081506071`}, {0.1825529`, 
0.079802714`}, {0.18490784`, 0.078130558`}, {0.18726275`, 
0.075548811`}, {0.18961764`, 0.074480295`}, {0.19197251`, 
0.072223406`}, {0.19432736`, 0.070366774`}, {0.19668218`, 
0.068165596`}, {0.19903698`, 0.068293295`}, {0.20139175`, 
0.066839873`}, {0.2037465`, 0.06539873`}, {0.20610123`, 
0.063254469`}, {0.20845593`, 0.062264695`}, {0.2108106`, 
0.06122402`}, {0.21316525`, 0.059284872`}, {0.21551987`, 
0.058103587`}, {0.21787447`, 0.057846178`}, {0.22022904`, 
0.056534087`}, {0.22258358`, 0.055681804`}, {0.2249381`, 
0.054555308`}, {0.22729259`, 0.053447653`}, {0.22964705`, 
0.050985052`}, {0.23200148`, 0.05112098`}, {0.23435589`, 
0.050515905`}, {0.23671026`, 0.049462284`}, {0.23906461`, 
0.048852687`}, {0.24141893`, 0.047111266`}, {0.24377322`, 
0.046178586`}, {0.24612748`, 0.045303114`}, {0.24848171`, 
0.045024691`}, {0.25083591`, 0.04453976`}, {0.25319008`, 
0.0435324`}, {0.25554422`, 0.043386064`}, {0.25789833`, 
0.042628797`}, {0.26025241`, 0.041504444`}, {0.26260645`, 
0.040537487`}, {0.26496046`, 0.040452459`}, {0.26731445`, 
0.039493138`}, {0.26966839`, 0.03839103`}, {0.27202231`, 
0.037801358`}, {0.27437619`, 0.037234967`}, {0.27673004`, 
0.036755139`}, {0.27908386`, 0.035998536`}, {0.28143764`, 
0.035237672`}, {0.28379139`, 0.035419304`}, {0.2861451`, 
0.034571123`}, {0.28849878`, 0.033495659`}, {0.29085242`, 
0.033491305`}, {0.29320603`, 0.032608865`}, {0.2955596`, 
0.033281853`}, {0.29791314`, 0.031811092`}, {0.30026664`, 
0.031652453`}, {0.30262011`, 0.031097333`}, {0.30497353`, 
0.030427169`}, {0.30732692`, 0.030131797`}, {0.30968028`, 
0.02974402`}, {0.31203359`, 0.028764876`}, {0.31438687`, 
0.028740458`}, {0.31674011`, 0.028269577`}, {0.31909331`, 
0.028133016`}, {0.32144647`, 0.027667524`}, {0.3237996`, 
0.026724803`}, {0.32615268`, 0.026212851`}, {0.32850573`, 
0.026603364`}, {0.33085873`, 0.026516127`}, {0.3332117`, 
0.025608039`}, {0.33556462`, 0.025019638`}};
```

Comment: If you copy as `InputForm` and paste, the integral will be readable on the site.  Also the symbol `I` is the imaginary unit, and functions have the form `f[x]`, with brackets instead of parentheses.  I'll leave fixing `I(q)` to you, since you should pick a different function name.  `data` should be formatted better, too, by indenting each line four spaces (or select and use the `{}` button above the edit window).

Comment: @Michael Have changed the symbol $I$ to $Int$ which stands for Intensity.

Comment: I guess the answer in the beginning requires to fit the intensity, `Int(q)` by some reasonable function, and then to solve integral equation `Int[q] = 4*Pi*Integrate[P[r]*(Sin[q*r]/(q*r)), {r, 0, Infinity}] `with respect to `P(r) `. It is, thus, more about integral equations, then about anything else. I suggest that the words "integral equation" should appear in the title of the question to attract attention of those who know how to solve such things. Another way would be as follows. If you know, how the function `P(r)`should look like in some parametric form, you might substitute

Comment: Continuation: this parametric form directly into the integral compare it with the data and vary parameters to provide the best fit. This approach may be more direct. But you need to have a good guess of the parametric representation of `P(r)`.

Comment: @Alexei  The problem is I do not have a clue about a viable form of P(r). Moreover Int(q) may undergo a non-monotonic change at some $q$ (in otherwords a crossover indicative of a transition at a $q$). So the direct approach is best.

Answer (score 4):

This answer contains no Mathematica, only mathematics.

Let $P$ be extended to negative input via $P(-x)=P(x)$, and let $k_q(x) = \sin(qx)/qx = \operatorname{sinc}\bigl(\frac q\pi x\bigr)$. Both $P$ and $k_q$ are even functions. You have
$$\begin{align}
I_q &= 4\pi\int_0^\infty P(r)k_q(r)\,\mathrm dr \\
&= 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(r)k_q(0-r)\,\mathrm dr \\
&= 2\pi(P*k_q)(0)
\end{align}$$
where $P*k_q$ is the convolution of $P$ and $k_q$, and is here being evaluated at $0$. Using the properties of the Fourier transform that
$$\begin{align}
\widehat{f*g} &= \hat f\hat g, \\
f(0) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat f(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi,
\end{align}$$
we obtain
$$\begin{align}
I_q &= 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat P(\xi)\hat k_q(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi \\
&= 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat P(\xi)\cdot\frac\pi q\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\pi\xi}{q}\right)\,\mathrm d\xi \\
&= \frac{2\pi^2}q\int_{-q/2\pi}^{q/2\pi}\hat P(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi
\end{align}$$
because the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is $\operatorname{rect}(\xi)$. Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d(qI_q)}{\mathrm dq} &= 2\pi^2\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq}\int_{-q/2\pi}^{q/2\pi}\hat P(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi \\
&= 2\pi^2\cdot\frac1{2\pi}\left(\hat P\left(\frac{-q}{2\pi}\right)+\hat P\left(\frac q{2\pi}\right)\right) \\
&= 2\pi\hat P\left(\frac q{2\pi}\right)
\end{align}$$
because $\hat P$ is also even. Thus you can estimate $\hat P$, the Fourier transform of $P$, directly by finite differencing the data.

Comment: Sort of like your answer, but how can I code that in MMA-v10? Any clues

Answer (score 3):

I would use a slightly different derivation but the concept is basically the same.

Here $I_q:=4\pi \int_0^{\infty}P(r)\frac{\sin qr}{qr}dr$. Hence $qI_q=4\pi \int_0^{\infty}P(r)\frac{\sin qr}{r}dr$. The derivative of $qI_q$ with respect to $q$ is

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dq}(qI_q)=4\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}P(r)\cos(qr)\,dr.
\end{equation}

This relation can be inverted to get $P(r)$. If we further assume that $I_q$ decays fast enough as $q\rightarrow \infty$, one could obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
P(r)&=&\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dq}(qI_q)\cos(qr)\,dq\\
&=&\frac{r}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}qI_q\sin(qr)\,dq\\
&=&\frac{-r}{2\pi^2}\frac{d}{dr}\int_{0}^{\infty}I_q\cos(qr)\,dq.
\end{eqnarray}

There are various ways to approximate the integral above with the given data. One could interpolate the data to obtain $I_q$ by using Interpolation then calculate the integral with NIntegrate. However, I doubt $I_q$ really decays fast enough for the given data.

Comment: You mentioned "fast enough".....can this phrase be quantified mathematically, so that I can see if your relation can be applied.